# Incorrect conclusion that "This condition will always return 'false'"

Tags: typescript

```
enum State {
  ONE,
  TWO
}

const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

class StateMachine {
  private state: State = State.ONE

  public async transitionA() {
    this.state = State.TWO
    await sleep(1000)
    if (this.state === State.ONE) { // <-- error
      console.log("It totally happened")
      this.state = State.TWO
    }
  }

  public async transitionB() {
    this.state = State.ONE
  }
}
const stateMachine = new StateMachine()
stateMachine.transitionA()
stateMachine.transitionB()
```

I get the following compile error on the indicated line:

```
Error:(14, 9) TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'State.TWO' and 'State.ONE' have no overlap.
```

However, the condition is `true` in the above example. Is this a bug/feature in the compiler? Is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Control Flow Analysis and you can read more about the limitations in it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

The simplest solution is to use a type assertion to force the compiler into thinking `state` is just `State` not the enum literal type `State.ONE`

```
public async transitionA() {
    this.state = State.TWO as State
    await sleep(1000)
    if (this.state === State.ONE) { // <-- error
    console.log("It totally happened")
    this.state = State.TWO
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a limitation to me, but like a huge bug. The declared type of the variable is State, not State.TWO. Why does it assume that its type is State.TWO? It's a variable: by definition, its value is thus... variable, and thus can become something other than State.TWO. If the variable was local, I would understand, but it's an instance field, not a local variable.

Comment: @JBNizet The compiler analyses the code, and sees that on the first line you assign `this.state = State.TWO`, so since there is no other assignment in the function it assumes that the `private` field will be `State.TWO`.

Comment: I understand that, but the assumption is incorrect, and shouldn't be made in this case, since the variable is not local.

Comment: @JBNizet we can quibble about what carve-outs should be made for `async` functions, and for private fields used in async functions. But the general principles of flow analysis are outlined in the GitHub link I provided and the limitations apply to both fields and local vars.

Comment: @JBNizet And I don't think any carve-outs are made specifically for async functions, there is a comment about them in the GitHub thread. I agree with you that for async functions the compiler probably should reset its assumptions after an async call but then again they did not implement it like that at least for now ..

Comment: I agree, and upvoted your answer. I just don't agree about calling a "limitation" what is clearly a "bug". I'd call a limitation a case where the compiler doesn't detect an impossible condition. Not a case where it tells you that a condition is impossible when it clearly is possible, especially when it assigns another type to a variable than the one you explicitly declared.

Comment: @JBNizet limitation/bug it's all in the eye of the beholder I guess. I used their term for consistency, but we can call it a bug :)

Comment: Thanks for the info and workaround. In the Github issue you linked, a similar case is mentioned: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-439610488

Comment: If you look at line 9 of the code, OP is already defining it as a State type.  IMO definitely a bug which unfortunately still exists today (December 2022) v4.9.3

Comment: @Phil Still not a bug. line 12 sets `this.state`, so CFA will take this into account when analyzing `transitionA`. It is incorrect, but it's in the class of limitation, not bug.